# Export runnable JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I try to export a Java-Project with different Libraries included a JavaFX GUI and lots of different stuff to a runnable JAR file.
When i run my project in eclipse there is no problem. But when I try to export it to a runnable JAR file and afterwards i try to start is it never opens a window there is just a process running in the background.

I don't know how to describe my problem better. But maybe you can help me with this information already.

(using eclipse)

Comment: Have you tried to launch your application with java -jar myapplication.jar and look if throws any errors ?

Comment: hmm seems to work, but now there are missing some gui elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting a jar for a javafx project in eclipse, has always ended up with some problem or the other for me. May be, though I am not sure, eclipse packages the jar as per `Swing` configurations, where as `Javafx` needs some peculiar configuration. For details visit

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm

For an easier method, you can always port your project to `NetBeans` and use the jar that is created by it ! The `jar` created by `Netbeans` works flawlessly for me !

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the option "Export Runnable JAR File" and "Extract required libraries into generated JAR".

Try also adding the jfxrt.jar to the Java Build Path when not using Java 8.

Comment: In my case jfxrt.jar will be added automatically by eclipse and i've already tried to Extract required libraries into generated JAR and i tried the two other options already.

Answer (score 0):

The probable issue is like the dependent Jars are not in place. Are you providing any VM arguments to run your Application from Eclipse.

If Yes, then please note you can't provide VM arguments in the Runnable Jar.

Solution is , you can use "Launch4J" to pass VM arguments to your application.

" **VM arguments will not be part of the runnable JAR. Arguments can be passed on the command line when launching the JAR**".

While creating the Runnable Jar, check first checkbox "Extract Required Libraries into generated JAR".

Cheers .. :)

Subh